# Paged UIScrollView with UIImageViews only showing first UIImageVIew

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am working on a paged UIScrollView, but it only wants to show the first UIImageView within it. I add each UIImageView at an offset of the width of the scroll view, so that should create each page. When run, it says the scroll view is the right number of pages, but the images don't show.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
int numSlides = NUM_TUTORIAL_SLIDES;
    NSString *fileName;
    UIImageView *slideImageView;
    CGRect slideFrame;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numSlides; i++)
    {
        slideFrame.origin.x = self.tutorialScrollView.frame.size.width * (i-1);
        slideFrame.origin.y = 0;
        slideFrame.size = self.tutorialScrollView.frame.size;

        slideImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:slideFrame];


        if([[AppManager sharedManager] is4inchScreen])
        {
            fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slide%d4in@2x.png", i];
        }

        else
        {
            fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slide%d@2x.png", i];
        }

        slideImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil]];

        [self.tutorialScrollView addSubview:slideImageView];

        [slideImageView release];
    }

    self.tutorialScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tutorialScrollView.frame.size.width * numSlides, self.tutorialScrollView.frame.size.height);

    self.tutorialScrollView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: The only comment I have, is why are you adding the "@2x" suffix to the image name? You should try: `@"Slide%d.png"`

Comment: @2x is for the retina. I am not putting in non-retina images, so for retina it will be retina and non-retina will just not be non-retina with the same image

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change the following code will help

```
    slideImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue had to do with rounding the corners of the scroll view.

I had this code:

```
//Round header image
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.tutorialScrollView.bounds
                                               byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(DEFAULT_CORNER_RADIUS_HEADER, DEFAULT_CORNER_RADIUS_HEADER)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.tutorialScrollView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

and apparently that causes issues with the scroll view